# Check if a particular app installed or not flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, installed-applications

I want to implement conditions in my existing app that a particular app is installed or not.

**Conditions:**

`the first app is that which is I'm going to build`

`Second app that is required for run first app`

1. If the app is installed (Second app) then run `HomePage()` in the first app
2. If the app is not installed then show a pop-up or alert for install the app.

**Root Code of the first app**

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
    future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return MaterialApp(
              home: Splash(),
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            );
          } else {
            return StreamBuilder(
              stream: Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ConnectivityResult> snapshot) {
                return snapshot.data == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
                        snapshot.data == ConnectivityResult.wifi
                    ? MaterialApp(
                        title: 'mFollower',
                        theme: ThemeData(
                          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        home: Homepage(),
                        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                      )
                    : NoInternet();
              },
            );
          }

        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the package [device_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps/) package. This will return the list of apps installed in the Android device.

```
// All the apps installed in the device
List<Application> apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications();
```

So for your requirement you can do something like below

```
Future<bool> isAppInstalled() {
    return DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications().then((value) =>
        value.any((element) => element.packageName == 'com.example.app')); // Your app package id to check.
}
```

And inside `build` method use Future builder to get the result.

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: apps(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data) {
            // App is installed
            return Container(
              color: Colors.green,
            );
          } else {
            // App is not installed
            return Container(color: Colors.redAccent);
          }
        })
```

> **Unfortunately this plugin is supported only for ANDROID**

Comment: thanks for your answer, but maybe you don't understand what I'm going to say exactly.

Comment: Let's understand with a real-life example:
There are two apps on my phone i.e. `First App` and `Second App`.

`Second App` already developed and published. `First app` under development.

If the `Second App` is installed in my mobile then open the `First App` `HomePage()` state otherwise redirect to another state like `noInstalled State()`. I have shared the root code of `First App` in it a condition already applied for check internet connection

Comment: OK. So you are trying to open the `First app` if it is installed in the device when user attempts to open the `Second app` which is already installed. 

User -> Opens Second App -> If First app is installed open it or else say some error ?

Comment: Yes exactly. How can I implement in existing code which are above

Comment: You need to implement the above logic in the second app.

Comment: I'm new to flutter so unable to implement. Can you help me with this

Comment: You can try the above app with default template app that will be created when creating a new flutter project.  Use that to perform your logic and then implement them in the actual app.